# C# date format over 1 day

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I'm trying to format a date from now, to few seconds, hours, maybe days, similar as Clash of Clans working timers Like this :

```
System.DateTime dateTime = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
dateTime = dateTime.AddSeconds(80000);

return dateTime.ToString("H'h' mm'min'");
```

It works great actually, I get '22h 13min', only for minutes and hours. If I try to print days with it, like this :

```
System.DateTime dateTime = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
dateTime = dateTime.AddSeconds(80000);

return dateTime.ToString("d'd' H'h' mm'min'");
```

I'll have '1d 22h 13min' returned. So for example if I try to convert 1 day to second (86400sec), this code will return 2 days, instead of 1 day.

How can I solve this problem properly without tricks like hard substract by 1 the day returned ?

EDIT1:
For example, expected result for one day is :

```
System.DateTime dateTime = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
dateTime = dateTime.AddSeconds(86400);
return dateTime.ToString("d'j' H'h' mm'min'");
```

return 2d 0h 00min, instead of 1d 0h 00min.

Comment: Can't understand your scenario and your expected result. Can you add the code with "try to convert 1 day to second (86400sec), this code will return 2 days, instead of 1 day."?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you please be more specific? When you add `86400`, it will return `2d 0h 00min` as expected.

Comment: For `DateTime`, day is the day of the month.  What you want is a `TimeSpan`.

Comment: @SonerGönül oh ok, I thought I started from 0 day 0 hour 0 minute

Comment: @dmo Hours and minutes do start from 0.  But there is no zero day because dates start from 1.  Note that you cannot do this `new DateTime(1970,1,0);`.

Comment: @dmo Time parts starts with 0 but day part starts with 1 since there is no 0 as a day number of month in Gregorian Calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `DateTime`, day is the day of the month. What you want is a `TimeSpan`.

```
var span = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(80000);
Console.WriteLine(span.ToString(@"d'd 'h'h 'm'min'"));
```

outputs

> 0d 22h 13min

Comment: Thanks a lot all, I was just using wrong lib, TimeSpan will do what I want :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code `dateTime = dateTime.AddSeconds(80000);` will assign the value `1/1/1970 10:13:20` to the `dateTime` variable, hence  you are getting the output as `1d 22h 13min` by `dateTime.ToString("d'd' H'h' mm'min'");`. So if you want to get the next day you can use `dateTime = dateTime.AddDays(1);` or add it as seconds as you did. ie.,  `dateTime = dateTime.AddSeconds(86400);`

Answer (score 0):

[The `"d"` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dSpecifier) returns the day number of month. Since you add `1` day to 1st January, it will be 2nd January and that's why this specifier returns `2`.

If I understand clearly, you might wanna use `TimeSpan` instead.

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(86400);
ts.ToString("d'd 'h'h 'mm'min'"); // 1d 0h 00min
```

or

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(80000);
ts.ToString("d'd 'h'h 'mm'min'"); // 0d 22h 13min
```

Then you can format this value.

Or you can use [`DateTime.AddDays` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays) to subctact 1 day like

```
dateTime = dateTime.AddDays(-1);
```

for your `dateTime` if you *really* wanna use `DateTime`.